# MVVM - data layer of models and viewmodels

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, mvvm

I am refactoring my application to utilize MVVM. I used to keep a `List<Product>` variable in the Application class that I was able to bind a ListView to. This List made up my Data layer. The Page with this ListView is a master/detail layout. With MVVM, I am thinking that the List should now hold instances of the ProductModel as it is the data layer. If I should be binding to ViewModels, do I need a separate List of ViewModels too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to take a different perspective on MVVM.  Your View is the page with the controls (XAML) and your ViewModel is the glue between your data model and the page.  The View's entire data context will be set to the ViewModel (done either in the XAML directly or in code-behind depending on which MVVM camp you subscribe to).

In your example, you would move `List<Product>` onto the ViewModel as `ObservableCollection<Product>` and make sure that your ViewModel implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  INotifyPropertyChanged is the contract the View uses to know when to update it's binding.  You will use an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of a list because `ObservableCollection<T>` implements INotifyPropertyChanged itself.

Your View's DataContext property will be set to an instance of the ViewModel.  On the View, the ListBox control's `ItemsSource` property will be set to bind to the `Product` collection.  You can then have methods inside of your ViewModel that will be responsible for communicating with your data store to populate the observable collection.

### ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<Product> _products = null;
    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
    {
       get { return _products; }
       set
       {
           if( _products != value )
           {
               _products = value;

               if( this.PropertyChanged != null )
               {
                   this.PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( "Products" ) );
                }
            }
        }
     }

     // have code in here that loads the Products list from your data store (i.e. service call to database)
}
```

### View Code-Behind

```
public MyView()
{   
    InitializeComponent(); 
    this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
}
```

### View

```
<ListBox
    ItemsSource={Binding Path=Products, Mode=OneWay}
    SelectedItem={Binding Path=SelectedProduct, Mode=TwoWay}
    ...
/>
```

Comment: Ok, So lets say I have a class `Cart` that contains this `List<Product>` along with a few other details. This `Cart` is a ViewModel. I need `Product` to be represented in a Model and ViewModel because in this Master/Detail layout, there is some configuration logic that should not be in the Model. So my `CartViewModel` has a List of Products, but should they be the ViewModel version?

Comment: You might be over-complicating it.  The ViewModel will contain many properties for your View to bind to.  You typically will have a single ViewModel for each View (and by View I mean your whole page - not site but page).  Cart will then be a view-model property on the ViewModel.  Since Cart contains a list of products, you can bind the ListBox to that List by saying `ItemsSource={Binding Path=Cart.Products}`.

Comment: Take a look at my response here to see if that clarifies anything: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6154582/20133

Comment: You don't want a ViewModel per-control but rather per-page (excluding a few exceptions to this).

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanations. Correct me if I'm wrong but it looks like I should have `CartViewModel` (view model for this whole page) which contains a `ObservableCollection<ProductViewModel>` as a property. My ListBox/master will bind to that collection, and the detail area will bind to the selected Item. It's looking like the `ProductViewModel` should contain/wrap the `ProductModel`.

Comment: Yes, that would work.  I will suggest not bothering wrapping `Product` with a `ProductViewModel` because once your view is setup, the binding can cascade down the object tree without requiring a new ViewModel for each child container (if that makes sense).  You can easily have `ObservableCollection<Product>` in the CartViewModel along with a `SelectedProduct` property which the details area is bound to (all with a single ViewModel).  Now if your Product requires a whole page, then have that page use its own ViewModel.

Comment: Yes, what you're saying is true, but for my needs that would kind of violate the principles of MVVM. I have logic related to the modification of a Product in the ProductViewModel that should not be in the ProductModel. Rolling it all into ProductModel/Product would be adding irrelevant presentation logic to the business/data layer. Regardless, you get the green check :-). Thanks again for your help and patience, I'm new to MVVM but its really starting to click.